# Reset/normalize <button> to act like <a>

Tags: css, button

How do I make the styling of `<button>` elements resemble `<a>` elements as closely as possible?

I don't need link-specific `text-decoration: underline; color: blue;` and such - I'm resetting those anyway. Basically, I want the `<button>` to be like plain text until I apply classes.

Background: In a JavaScript app, I have click handlers bound to `<a>` elements. Those `<a>` elements don't have a natural `href`, which messes up keyboard accessibility in some browsers. It seems that replacing `<a>` with `<button>` would reflect the intent of the element better. But when I use `<button>`, the browser messes up the styling badly. How do I stop browsers from messing up the styling?

Answer (score 1):

you can reset your `button`

like this:

```css
button, button:active, button:focus{
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none
}
```

```html
<button>test button as a link</button>
```

Comment: You might want to add some text to your button element so it can be seen in the results ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for removing most of the styling for me:

```
button, button:active, button:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwxo97ag/1/